# Firestore Ignore empty string value in query

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I have a firebase database of "users" with bunch of fields. I also have a filter that executes a query on those fields and returns the filtered users. The problem is the query can get an object where the location value is an empty string, **if the value is `""` I want ignore that `.where` line of code but execute the other ones.** I've tried converting the value to `undefined` and `null` but `undefined` throws an error and `null` displays no users.

```
exports.filterUsers = (req, res) => {    
 db.collection("users")
.where("gender", "==", req.body.gender)
.where("age", "<=", req.body.maxAge)
.where("age", ">=", req.body.minAge)
.where("location", "==", req.body.location)
.get()
```

Comment: You can simply choose not to add a where clause if you don't need it, as illustrated in the duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the [`where()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query#where) method returns a [`Query`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Query), you can do as follows:

```
let query = db.collection("users")
.where("gender", "==", req.body.gender)
.where("age", "<=", req.body.maxAge)
.where("age", ">=", req.body.minAge);

if (req.body.location === "") {
   query = query.where("location", "==", req.body.location);
}

query.get()...
```